# perform operation while machine is locked!

Tags: windows, java, automation

i have created a program in java which will emulate user activity in windows operating system(like clicking left mouse button),but as soon as i lock my system the activity also stops.
Is there any way to keep it running.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you could try is to [disconnect from your session](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321705) instead of locking it...

How would your program be able to click things that aren't clickable anymore?

If you need an alternative way to perform your operations you should ask a question on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Being clickable with physical mouse is not the same as being clickable by a program which is on the same winstation. The latter should still work.

Comment: It depends on the way it is written... As the activity stops he is using the way that would need the window to be active and visible to the user, there is indeed another way that allows one to directly send click events to an application without going through the AutoIt alike automation routine. But he should ask on SO how he could do that in Java if my first suggestion doesn't work...

Comment: For example >>>>if u start a for loop and lock the system(win+L) ..i can see it will continue to run(if u chk after 1 min the count of loop is increasd) but the activity like mouse move will stop...that means the program is still running but the mouse movement is stopped...so i want to know what exactly happens  when we lock the winodws machine.

Comment: The program will indeed continue to run but you will be unable to interact with the mouse and keyboard. This is because your session is locked for security reasons and you can not interact with that session. the session can't interact with you either...

Comment: So, if you want to perform an operation as the title mentioned, you could try StackOverflow and ask how you can do your operation in another way.